# JSON error when requesting resources from Azure Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm using the example from https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/confidential_client_secret_sample.py. My aim is to grab the URL to report on the number emails read, sent and received by user.

I've been playing around with the endpoint setting and decided to hardcode it whilst testing.  The Graph API resources is at GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getEmailActivityUserCounts(period='D7')](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getEmailActivityUserCounts(period=%27D7%27)).

The code i'm using is as follows.

```
if "access_token" in result:
    # Calling graph using the access token
    graph_data = requests.get(  # Use token to call downstream service
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getEmailActivityUserCounts(period=\'D7\')",
        #config["endpoint"],
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']},).json()
    print("Graph API call result: %s" % json.dumps(graph_data, indent=2))
```

I believe i am correctly escaping D7 but when i run the code i get the following error.

```
Exception has occurred: JSONDecodeError
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

To add to this, the JSON is in the format of, when i removed the string and uncommented #config["endpoint"],

```
{
    "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXX/",
    "client_id": "XXX",
    "scope": ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"],
    "secret": "XXX",
    "endpoint": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getEmailActivityUserCounts(period='D7')"
}
```

Is this because the JSONDecoder can't decode the escaped characters for D7?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully as below:***

I created an Azure AD application and granted **API Permission**:

[image]

To retrieve the report on the number emails read, sent and received by user, I used the below Python code:

```py
import requests
import urllib
import json
import csv
import os
 
client_id = urllib.parse.quote_plus('ClientID')
client_secret = urllib.parse.quote_plus('ClientSecret')
tenant = urllib.parse.quote_plus('TenantID')
auth_uri = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + tenant \
+ '/oauth2/v2.0/token'
auth_body = 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=' + client_id \
+ '&client_secret=' + client_secret \
+ '&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default'
authorization = requests.post(auth_uri, data=auth_body,
headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
})
token = json.loads(authorization.content)['access_token']

graph_uri = \
'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getEmailActivityUserCounts(period=%27D7%27)'
response = requests.get(graph_uri, data=auth_body,
headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token})
print("response:",response.text)
```

**I am able to get the report successfully like below:**

[image]